# C programming: Interval Division

Tags: c, intervals, division

I'm trying to divide the interval `*[a,b]* in *npt*` points saved in an array of float variables.

I need that `*a* and *b*` be always present in the final array and that `*npt*` can be a varied as I want.

I tried with:

```
delta = (b - a) / ((double) npt);
for (i = 0; i < npt; i++) {
    x[i] = a + i * delta;
}
```

But it doesn't work as I expected. 
Any help is appreciated, thank you !

Have a nice day.

Comment: Are `a` and `b` integers? What exactly isn't working as expected? That `b` does not end up in the float array?

Comment: No, *a* and *b* are *double* too and yes, *b* sometimes does not appear in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `npt` points you will have `npt-1` intervals.

Change the first line into:

```
delta=(b-a)/(npt-1.0);
```